# The process `com.broadcom.mes.systemextension` causes 100% CPU usage, what is it for?

Tags: cpu, kernel-extensions

As title. I have searched about `com.broadcom.mes.systemextension` but from their website I still don't know what it is for. As a NeoVim(you can think it as Vim) user when I scrolling through a result list from CLI tools `rg`(ripgrep) and `fd`(find), this CPU usage of this process goes from 5% to 105% and the temperature of my computer goes straight up to 80 Celsius. I really want to stop this process but I don't know whether it will be serious side-effect to my computer. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Google tells me it's part of Symantec Endpoint protection & has a known issue. See https://knowledge.broadcom.com/external/article/184880/macos-1015x-machines-experience-high-cpu.html

I can't test this theory, as Broadcom requires client login to access. If this is a company Mac, refer to your IT department.

> **Issue/Introduction**
> High CPU use may be experienced on some macOS 10.15.x machines running the 14.2 RU2 release of Symantec Endpoint Protection (SEP). The process involved is the new com.symantec.mes.systemextension.

> **Cause**
> Due to changes made in macOS 10.15, scan operations with autoprotect were happening unnecessarily.

> **Resolution**
> This is resolved in Symantec Endpoint Protection version 14.2 RU2 MP1 build b5576 and is available via the [Broadcom Download Center](https://support.broadcom.com/download-center/download-center.html)

Comment: That page says the relevant process is `com.symantec.mes.systemextension`, which is different than the one mentioned in the question, `com.broadcom.mes.systemextension`

Comment: @user125355 - Broadcom owns what remains of Symantec.

Comment: I wasn't able to find the download :'(

Comment: @ChrisGeirman - even after login?

Comment: @Tetsujin even after logging in unfortunately. I end up being redirected to https://support.broadcom.com/group/ecx/downloads which has a page with 2 options to proceed which says "Looks like you don't have any product entitlements. brows our range of products" -OR- "Don't know your site ID? build your profile and get access to your entitlements" Neither option lead to a fruitful conclusion

Comment: Endpoint Protection is usually corporate software, so it would be the company's profile that needs to be logged in. If not, you'll have to contact Broadcom/Symantec.